# Which Java Runtime Exception to Use When Missing an InitialContext Definition

Tags: java, exception, servlets, runtimeexception, initial-context

I am programming a Java Servlet application which needs certain environment variables and JNDI definitions to be present. These are defined in `server.xml` file. Using default values is not possible. So the program needs to throw a runtime (unchecked) exception. But which one? If none of the subclasses of `java.lang.RuntimeException` is suitable, I guess we will need to create a new type.

Comment: `MissingPropetiesException`, `AssertionError`, `WhatEverYouLikeException`? you want a *name* basically?

Comment: Yes, a name, or rather - if possible - an existing RuntimeException childclass.

Comment: there are `430` as far as I see... but this is a bit crazy, IMO. Choose whatever name you feel fits best, and *I would* create a new one like `MissingStartupPropertiesException`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use exceptions already defined, but I just usually implement my own, because I can always quickly recognize it when it is thrown. (It tells you more, just by having your project's classpath.)

```
public class MissingInitialContextException extends RuntimeException {
    public MissingInitialContextException() {
    }

    public MissingInitialContextException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public MissingInitialContextException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public MissingInitialContextException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }

    public MissingInitialContextException(String message, Throwable cause, boolean enableSuppression, boolean writableStackTrace) {
        super(message, cause, enableSuppression, writableStackTrace);
    }
}
```

You can auto generate classes like this in most IDE. (IDEA, after you created the class, ALT+ENTER and override methods from the RuntimeException class)

Why use custom exceptions.:

- You can use your IDE's find implementations and other search functions to locate usages
- In some frameworks, like in Spring Boot, you can decorate your exceptions with annotations and quickly define the response text and http error code.
- You can change the exception's implementation later.
- You can define automatic break on exception in your IDE for your custom exception, while if you would do this for a built in one, your debugger would stop in unexpected lines.
- You can avoid unintentionally catching other library's exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

**java.lang.NullPointerException**

When the configuration of the application is not (yet) complete the variables will probably be null, a NullPointerException seems appropriate. This exception is pretty generic but can be customized with a specific detail message in the constructor.

From the API:

> Applications should throw instances of this class to indicate other illegal uses of the null object.
>
> - When accessing or modifying the field of a null object.

```
throw new NullPointerException("environment variable XX is missing");
```

Comment: I would not use NullPointerException. I think they are always the programmer's fault. But in this case the guilty party is actually the Application Server config manager...